# Automatically adding spaces (tracking) between letters in math mode?

Tags: automation, letterspacing

A tool that I have no control over produces the following output:

```
\[\mForall{v1 v2 v3 : \mNat{} \mPlus{} \mQuot{}}{a \mLt{} b \mAnd{} b \mLt{} c \mImpl{} a \mLt{} c}\]
```

All that I can do is redefine the `\m...` macros. The final objective is to get something akin to:

```
forall a \, b \, c \: : \: \mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Q} : ... . \: a < b \wedge b < c \implies a < c
```

All of this is easy except for one thing: the spacing in `\mForall`. I guess I need to split its first argument around the colon, and replace spaces in the first half with thin math spaces, leaving the second half untouched.

Can I achieve this easily with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Does `\mForall` always have the argument `<variables> : ...`? And are variable spaced in the code? I don't understand the change from `v1`, `v2` and `v3` to `a`, `b` and `c`, though.

Comment: Indeed; it's always `{a b c d ...: some complex expression}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}


%[1] to remove spurious {}
\newcommand{\mNat}[1]{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\mPlus}[1]{+}
\newcommand{\mQuot}[1]{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\mLt}[1]{<}
\newcommand{\mAnd}[1]{\land}
\newcommand{\mImpl}[1]{\Rightarrow}

\newcommand\mForall[2]{\forall #1:#2}

\begin{document}

\[\mForall{a b c : \mNat{} \mPlus{} \mQuot{}}{a \mLt{} b \mAnd{} b \mLt{} c \mImpl{} a \mLt{} c}\]


\def\mForall#1#2{\forall \xaddsp #1:#2}
\def\xaddsp#1 {%
\ifx:#1:\else
#1\,\expandafter\xaddsp
\fi}
\[\mForall{a b c : \mNat{} \mPlus{} \mQuot{}}{a \mLt{} b \mAnd{} b \mLt{} c \mImpl{} a \mLt{} c}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `expl3` version; the first argument to `\mForall` is split at the colon and the first part is processed as another sequence, adding `\,` between each item.

The second part and the second argument are simply typeset separated by colons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mForall}{mm}
 {
  \mForallFirst{#1} : #2
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mForallFirst}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_tmpa_seq \c_colon_str { #1 }
  \clement_split_vars:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
  :
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \clement_split_vars:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \forall
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \, }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clement_split_vars:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mNat}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\mPlus}{+}
\newcommand{\mQuot}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\mLt}{<}
\newcommand{\mAnd}{\land}
\newcommand{\mImpl}{\Rightarrow}

\begin{document}

\[\mForall{a b c : \mNat{} \mPlus{} \mQuot{}}{a \mLt{} b \mAnd{} b \mLt{} c \mImpl{} a \mLt{} c}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; it works perfectly. I had trouble deciding between the two solution, so I went with the one that I understood best. I hope it's an ok criterion.

Comment: @Clément The worst one? `;-)`

Comment: @Clément seems excellent idea to me:-)

Comment: Oh well; I upvoted both answers; thanks egreg and David for all your help!